# how can i set the zone of current Machine in date format?

Tags: javascript, vb.net

i'm working at VB.net project, what i want is to change the zone "GMT" in a date to send it to another application.
so that when a destination get this date it can find the zone. so i want to modify a zone of date to any zone i want

Comment: i can get the zone from any date but i can't set it

Comment: i want to modify the zone of the date

Answer (score 0):

Look here for converting timezones. However it is in C# but it is straightforward to convert it to VB.Net:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2006/10/03/system.timezone2-starter-guide-_5b00_kathy-kam_5d00_.aspx